# SSL Error on using Amazon ELB

Tags: ssl, amazon-web-services, https, amazon-ec2, amazon-elb

We are using amazon elb for load balancing. We have an SSL Certificate which identifies our domain with www (www.domain.com). We have added redirects to our apache conf to redirect non www requests to www.

The problem we are now facing is when a user requests for https://domain.com users see a warning that connection is not private.

We feel this is because ELB handles SSL termination before the apache gets the opportunity to redirect. Our certificate is for www.domain.com and not domain.com.

What can we do to overcome this problem? Should we get an SSL cert for multiple sub domains (both www and non www)? We would prefer different solution as SSL certs for multiple sub domains are expensive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only solution is using the correct certificate for the task.  ELB is behaving cocorrectly, because the browser *has to* negotiate SSL *before* telling the server which hostname it's looking for, unless you're using SNI (which you aren't, because that involves multiple different certs).

You should not have to pay, or pay very much, to have your "www.example.com" certificate (re-) issued with an additional Subject Alternative Name of "example.com," which solves the issue, making the cert valid for both domains.

Comment: Got a new cert from digicert with www.domain.com as primary domain and domain.com as Subject Alternative Name. Thank you!